# PaperJs Add 2 raster as 2 symbols in the same project

Tags: javascript, arrays, paperjs

I have this project in paperjs:

```
    var url  = "http://www.clker.com/cliparts/q/I/s/P/E/3/yellow-umbrella-md.png";
raster = new Raster(url);
raster.rotate(10);
raster.scale(0.4);

var url2 = "https://images.vexels.com/media/users/3/145373/isolated/preview/98721f602aa3fadb040e0a161ab3f966-waterdrop-vislumbrante-vis-o-ilustra--o-by-vexels.png";
secondRaster = new Raster(url);
secondRaster.scale(0.9);


var count = 150;

var symbol = new Symbol(raster);
var secondSymbol = new Symbol(secondRaster);




for (var i = 0; i < count; i++) {
    // The center position is a random point in the view:
    var center = Point.random() * view.size;
    var placedSymbol = symbol.place(center);

    placedSymbol.scale(i / count);

}

function onFrame(event) {
    // Run through the active layer's children list and change
    // the position of the placed symbols:
    for (var i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        var item = project.activeLayer.children[i];

        // Move the item 1/20th of its width to the right. This way
        // larger circles move faster than smaller circles:
        item.position.y += item.bounds.width / 80;

        // If the item has left the view on the right, move it back
        // to the left:
        if (item.bounds.bottom > view.size.width) {
            item.position.y = -item.bounds.width;
        }
    }
}
```

The first raster has a symbol works good, but the second can't make it work... I read about to add more than one symbol to project.activeLayer.children but don't work. Even if I do a group of an array with both symbols also don't show up.
I read in a post that symbols can't be added as a group. Being that be true, it should be ok to be added even though isolated...
Anybody had done something similar?
Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are some mistakes in your code:

- The most important one, that make you think that the second raster doesn't work, is that you are creating the second raster with the variable `url` instead of `url2`. So both rasters use the same image as source...
- You need to place the second symbol like you do with the first one otherwise it will never get rendered.
- When iterating through active layer children, make sure to iterate over all children by using `project.activeLayer.children.length` (as you are placing `count * 2` symbols).
- When checking for bottom reaching items, use `height` instead of `width`.

Here is a [sketch](http://sketch.paperjs.org/#V/0.11.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) demonstrating the solution.

```
var COUNT = 10;

var raster = new Raster('http://www.clker.com/cliparts/q/I/s/P/E/3/yellow-umbrella-md.png');
raster.rotate(10);
raster.scale(0.4);

var secondRaster = new Raster('https://images.vexels.com/media/users/3/145373/isolated/preview/98721f602aa3fadb040e0a161ab3f966-waterdrop-vislumbrante-vis-o-ilustra--o-by-vexels.png');
secondRaster.scale(0.15);

var symbol = new Symbol(raster);
var secondSymbol = new Symbol(secondRaster);

for (var i = 1; i <= COUNT; i++) {
    // first symbol
    symbol.place(Point.random() * view.size).scale(i / COUNT);
    // second symbol
    secondSymbol.place(Point.random() * view.size).scale(i / COUNT);
}

function onFrame(event) {
    for (var i = 0; i < project.activeLayer.children.length; i++) {
        var item = project.activeLayer.children[i];

        item.position.y += item.bounds.height / 80;

        if (item.bounds.bottom > view.size.height) {
            item.position.y = -item.bounds.height;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. How could I miss url2??!:)  But if I want to use each item with a diferent code, for example, one goes right, other goes down, makes sense use the count for one and second count for other, each with their own for loop? Im saying that I already tried. It works better than if I only use the loop trhu the  project.activeLayer.children